# Yii2 Export redirects to destination page

Tags: php, export-to-csv, yii2

i'm currently implementing an export function for our yii2 based application. (An humhub module)
I use for this the "kartik-v/yii2-export" module.

The action contains:

```
$gridColumns = [
  ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
  'id',
  'language',
  'time_zone',
  ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
];

$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
  'sql' => 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE status=:status'
]);

return $this->render('export',[
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'gridColumns' => $gridColumns
]);
```

The view contains:

```
echo ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => $gridColumns
    ]);
```

When I klick on the export function a new popup windows opens with an information that it creates the file now. After a few seconds it should start a download, but redirects to the destination page.

Do I need to add something to the controller or did I do anything else wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: While debugging I found out that inside the module in the init function:
    `$this->_triggerDownload = !empty($_POST) &&
            !empty($_POST[$this->exportRequestParam]) &&
            $_POST[$this->exportRequestParam];`
Always results in false, so it skips the downloading part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clearly defined if that you need the "exportRequestParam" needs to be set.

```
echo ExportMenu::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'columns' => $gridColumns,
  'exportRequestParam' => 'user'
]);
```

This way it works.